# How to know certificate authority status using C in VxWorks

Tags: certificate, status, authority

I am working on VxWorks platform for enrolling the certificate and developed the code using C language. But now I want add an API, so that before enrollment I would be able to check CA status (i.e. remote CA machine). I should not provide username and password too for checking status. CA can be single or 2 or 3 tier. Please anyone help me.